# Make Specific Words Bold Within HTML "Label"

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML code in which I'm trying to set the words "Product" and "Revenue Type" as bold text.  These words are contained within labels.   I've tried `<b>Product</b>`, `<strong>Product</strong>` & a few other html tags but could not get the words to display in bold.  The HTML tags themselves displayed instead  (e.g  `<b>` and `</b>`  actually displayed as if they were text I wanted to display.

Does anyone know how I can get this to work?  Any help would be appreciated.   My HTML is as follows:

```
<table role="presentation" id="main_block:cloneConfirmTable:0:checkboxList">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input name="main_block:cloneConfirmTable:0:checkboxList" id="main_block:cloneConfirmTable:0:checkboxList:0" value="1" type="checkbox" checked="checked"> 
            <label for="main_block:cloneConfirmTable:0:checkboxList:0">Product: Actuarial : Revenue Type: Fee</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input name="main_block:cloneConfirmTable:0:checkboxList" id="main_block:cloneConfirmTable:0:checkboxList:1" value="2" type="checkbox" checked="checked"> 
            <label for="main_block:cloneConfirmTable:0:checkboxList:1">Product: Administration : Revenue Type: Fee</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: What was the markup that you used that displayed the `<b>` as text?

Comment: There's no reason `<b>` shouldn't work (see http://codepen.io/paulroub/pen/rctsn for an example of your table with bold tags). Were the `<b>...</b>` tags in the actual, output HTML, or in a database or form designer somewhere, waiting to be turned into escaped text?

Comment: Hi,  Thanks for the help.  It's a bit strange as the markup is the same as that you have used Paul.  It's part of a Salesforce visualforce page.  I tried to add bold tag using Chrome's element inspector also but it also does not work.  the <b> and </b> tags are output from this also.

Comment: try b { font-weight:bold !important; } in your css (overriding the css from salesforce). Or set it as inline css if it still persist.

Comment: Hi @SalesforceQueries how did it go?

Answer (score 1):

It should work:

```
<label for="..."><strong>Product:</strong> ... : <strong>Revenue Type:</strong> ...</label>
```

Make sure you don't have something in your CSS that resets those. It would look like that:

```
strong {
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

If you find it, just remove it, the `strong` will then be bold as it should.

**[EDIT]**

Alright, so you can also force it yourself by adding at the end of your CSS file, or in `<style>` tags in your `<head>` element:

```
strong {
    font-weight: bold !important;
}
```

Comment: Hi Skwal,  Thanks for the suggestion.  The CSS is not a CSS file I have generated myself, but it is generated by Salesforce.  Thanks for the tip though all the same.

Comment: @SalesforceQueries It's too bad Salesforce removed basic style like this one. See my edited answer for the workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure If I got your question right but try to use a `<span>` tag around the words with a common class:

```
<span class="important">Product</span>:
```

With jQuery:

```
$('document').ready(function(){ 
     $(".important").css("font-weight","bold");
});
```

Or just add the css needed in your css file or in your html/inline (not recommended):

```
.important {font-weight:bold}
```

Comment: Hi Allende,  thanks for your suggestion. I will try this out and let you know if it works.

Comment: yw, let us know any update, seems you're kind of restricted because the css/html is generated by that tool/app, if you do a "view source code" how the <b></b> tags look like ? Is the html you posted the one from the generated page or the one you're editing ?

Comment: Hi,  I tried out the jQuery change and it did not work.  I'll try it out again later on to see if I was doing something incorrect (which is possible).  The HTML I had paster above was the generated on page version (without any bold tags added).

Comment: Could you generate the html with the span tags wrapping the words or didn appear as with bold tags ?